# UWP border wont use maximum space

Tags: xaml, chat, border, datatemplate, uwp-xaml

Here I am again...
I have a ListView which loads items and prints them in the screen.
Everything is fine except I can't really make the XAML to work as I want it to.

The ListView outputs the content according to the DataTemplate which is supposed to output a "chat-like" display.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MessageListDataTemplate" x:DataType="disc:IMessage">
        <Border Background="#2C2F33" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="Transparent" CornerRadius="5">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,2,0,0">
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text="{x:Bind Author,Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White" FontSize="14"/>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5,3,0,0" Text="{x:Bind Timestamp,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource TimeToStringConverter}}" Foreground="LightGray" FontSize="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Margin="10,2,0,0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="{x:Bind Content, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="#99AAB5" FontSize="20" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The code is functional and it outputs this:

[image]

Instead of having the board to be sized according to the size of the message I would like it to be equal to the size of the screen. I have tried everything I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following style for the ListView:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, something I didn't though of. Was that possible to be set in the DataTemplate ? Why couldn't I go to the border and set horizontal alligment to stretch ? Thanks again!

Comment: @KonKarapas DataTemplate is for the element represents the data item. While it is wrapped by an element called ListViewItem which could be styled through ItemContainerStyle. The default value of the HorizontalContentAlignment of a ListViewItem is Left. So the problem is about the ListViewItem, not something else. You can view the visual tree by debugging your app for more detail.